# Como separar um arquivo PDF linha por linha, em Java?

Tags: java, pdf

Preciso de um modo que eu consiga ler linha por linha de um arquivo pdf.

Estou lendo o arquivo pdf inteiro de uma vez nessa linha de comando:

```
String conteudo=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);
```

Porem preciso ler linha por linha, pois preciso saber qual a linha que esta minha ocorrência.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Que tal quebrar a string que você já obtém no seu código, fazendo a quebra onde encontrar os caracteres de quebra de linha? (geralmente \n e \r em alguma combinação).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim como a dica dada pelo @Renan, você já tem todo seu texto em uma variável String, ao invés de procurar o texto que você quer no PDF procure ele na sua String

```
//aqui voce tem toda a pagina em uma String
String pagina = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);

//separe em um vetor de Strings cada linha, o final da linha sempre será \n
String[] linhas = pagina.split("\n");

//agora percorra seu vetor de Strings procurando o texto que deseja
int numLinha = 1;
boolean achou = false;
for(String s: linhas) {
    //quando encontrar, marque um flag e caia fora do loop
    if(s.contains("o texto que eu quero")) {
        achou = true;
        break;
    }
    numLinha++;
}

//pronto, agora voce tem a linha que está o texto que procura
if(achou) {
    System.out.println("Seu texto está na linha:" + numLinha);
}
else {
    System.out.println("texto não encontrado");
}
```

Comment: E se o `\n` não der certo, tenta o `\r` ;) +1

Comment: @Renan Poisé, é sempre bom ressaltar isso pois pode ser que varie de caso para caso, mas no teste que eu fiz com a biblioteca itext (que é a que o autor tá usando) sempre colocava `\n` no final da linha. Valeu.