# Como passar um arquivo do JSP para o servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Tenho uma página .jsp, onde tenho um input file. Preciso abrir esse arquivo para utilizar as informações contidas nele.
Suponhamos que seja um pdf. Eu recebo esse pdf, envio para o servlet com o propósito de utilizar na minha aplicação JAVA.
O jeito mais fácil seria pegar o caminho todo do arquivo e enviá-lo numa string. Mas não sei se pode fazer isso e nem como se faz!
Outra coisa, era pegar o arquivo no .jsp mesmo e transformar o conteúdo todo em string. Então passar essa string para minha aplicação JAVA. Mas também não sei fazer isso.
Alguma solução?
Como posso pegar o arquivo e enviá-lo para minha aplicação?

Comment: Fiz alguns testes com o itext e percebi que existem zilhares maneiras diferentes de tratar o pdf em questão. Pelo que vi em outra pergunta sua você já tem uma certa familiaridade com o itext, por isso eu pergunto: poderia dizer exatamente qual seria a sua dúvida quanto a manipulação do arquivo pdf? A forma como enviar o pdf pode ser feito conforme eu fiz com o código abaixo, a diferença é que você não vai usar o FileReader, mas vai usar os métodos que o itext oferece.

Comment: nunca mexi com itext, mas tudo bem.
O que eu preciso é abrir o pdf e percorrer todo o texto contido nele. Irei percorrer cada palavra do pdf

Comment: Usou sim, talvez sem saber, mas usou, rs.. Veja: [Como separar um arquivo PDF linha por linha, em Java?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12650/3117) e aqui: [Class PdfTextExtractor](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfTextExtractor.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você precisa enviar um arquivo através de um elemento do tipo input="file" e ler o conteúdo dele.

Vou precisa fazer um projeto a exemplo da [resposta que eu dei na sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22578/3117):

A grande diferença é que você vai ter que usar um FileReader para ler o arquivo passado pelo seu input na página inicial.

Exemplo:

**index.html** - um html simples que envia um arquivo de um input file para um servlet

```
<body>
    <form method="get" action="LeArq.do">
        <input type="file" name="arquivo" size="chars" />
        <input type="submit" value="Envia Arquivo" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**Modelo.java** - uma classe muito simples

```
package com.example.model;

public class Modelo {
    public void trataArquivo(String str) {
        if(str.equals("4")) {
            System.out.println("achei a linha que tem escrito 4 nela!!");
        }
    }
}
```

**LeInputFile.java** - seu servlet, mapeado no DD como "LeArq.do"

```
package com.example.web;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.example.model.Modelo;

public class LeInputFile extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Modelo modelo = new Modelo();

        String endereco = req.getParameter("arquivo");
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();  
        String enderecoCompleto = context.getRealPath(endereco);
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(enderecoCompleto));
        String str;
        while((str = buff.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str); //apenas para você saber o que tem no seu arquivo
            modelo.trataArquivo(str);
        }
        buff.close();
    }
}
```

Se você ler um arquivo que possui o seguinte conteúdo:

> um teste
>   segunda linha
>   tres
>   4
>   5

A saída será:

> um teste
>   segunda linha
>   tres
>   4
>   achei a linha que tem escrito 4 nela!!
>   5

Eu fiz esse exemplo em um servidor local, talvez para um servidor remoto você tenha que concatenar o caminho completo onde ficará o arquivo, mas não tenho como testar agora, assim que eu testar eu te retorno.

Comment: com o BufferedReader eu consigo abrir .PDF?

Comment: @Pacíficão que dá dá, mas não é tão simples como ler o txt, deixa eu dar uma olhada aqui e ja te falo

Comment: @Pacíficão vc ja conseguiu ler o arquivo de texto? To fazendo uns testes com o pdf.

Comment: no meu projeto, eu não posso usar txt, só posso usar pdf.

Comment: descobriu algo @Math ?

Comment: @Pacíficão descobri que não sei exatamente do que você precisa, rs.. Você já mexeu com itext outras vezes, portanto se você conseguir fazer o upload de um pdf depois é só tratar com o itext ao invés do FileReader. Viu minha pergunta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23821/como-passar-um-arquivo-do-jsp-para-o-servlet/23851?noredirect=1#comment46855_23821)?

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, isso se chama file upload =)

Seguem ótimas referências sobre o assunto: [**Locaweb**](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Upload_com_JSP/JAVA) e [**codigofontes.com.br**](http://www.codigosfontes.com.br/upload-de-arquivos-com-jsp-e-apache-fileupload/).
Ambas têm código super simples de entender, não tenho mais nada  a acrescentar.

Fora isso me parece que você não compreendeu bem a questão "WEB" da coisa. O seu arquivo .jsp é processado no servidor, mas no fim das contas é interpretado pelo browser cliente... O servlet é uma simples classe que fica no servidor e aceita requisições através de socket. Note que um fica no cliente outro no server, a comunicação entre essas duas pontas é feita através do protocolo HTTP, não é simplesmente "passar" de um pro outro.

Sugiro que tente entender bem como funciona o (HTTP) `request / response` antes de qualquer coisa.

Att